# Can't seem to add char read from file to string buffer

Tags: string, assembly, x86, dos, x86-16

I'm working on a 8086 and need a subroutine to read the current line from a text file, putting the contents on a string buffer, except the linefeed. I'm also keeping track of how long the line is (in bytes) on `BX`. Basically what I'm doing is:

```
while read_new_char_from_file() != (\r or \n or EOF) add it to the buffer, inc bx
then increment bx to account for the linefeed, and return
```

I ran a few test cases and the byte count is correct, the loop stops when the byte is `\n`, as expected. However, the bytes don't seem to be added to my string buffer! The subroutine:

(`FGETC` reads one char from `FHANDLE` to `CBUFF` (updating the handle) and is working properly, nevertheless it can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/w0fGPdTz)).

```
FGETS PROC NEAR
    PUSH AX             ; (used by fgetc)
    PUSH CX             ; (used by fgetc)
    XOR BX, BX          ; clears our byte counter
    CLD                 ; positive BF (used by STOSB)
    LEA DI, SBUFFL      ; pointer to the string buffer (used by STOSB)
    FGETS_LOOP:         ; read loop
    CALL FGETC          ; read a new char from the file to CBUFF
    CMP AX, CX          ; partial read (EOF)?
    JNE FGETS_RET       ; return
    CMP CBUFF, 13       ; carriage return?
    JE FGETS_RET_I      ; return, increment byte count and handle to account for \r\n
    CMP CBUFF, 10       ; line feed?
    JE FGETS_RET_U      ; return, increment byte count and handle to account for \n
    MOV AL, CBUFF       ; char to be written to buff
    STOSB               ; store string byte (increments DI)
    INC BX              ; increment the byte counter
    JMP FGETS_LOOP      ; loop    
    FGETS_RET_U:        ; account for \n
    INC BX              ; increment byte counter
    JMP FGETS_RET       ; return
    FGETS_RET_I:        ; account for \r and \n
    ADD BX, 2           ; increment byte count by 2
    CALL FGETC          ; increment fhandle (to skip \n)
    FGETS_RET:          ; return...
    MOV AL, '$'         ; add 'end of string' char to the buffer
    STOSB               ; ...
    POP CX              ; pops
    POP AX              ; ...
    RET                 ; actually return
FGETS ENDP
```

The results of a test case:

String buffer (40 size and initialized with 'x's ending at '$' to be able to print it to the stdout and see the results):

```
SBUFFL DB 40 DUP ('x'),'$'  ; 4000 chars (4000 bytes)
```

File contents (lines ending at `\n`):

```
4,5
500,-1000,0,250,-300
4,0,1,2,3
3,4,3,2
5,1,2,3,2,1
2,2,3
```

Result of printing `SBUFFL` (via the DOS int to print a string, which is working) after calling `FGETS` with `FHANDLE` at the beginning of the file:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Which indicates the bytes read from the file weren't added to the buffer. However, Turbo Debugger shows the byte count (`BX`) and the stop condition (`\n`) are correct for a read on the first line:

[image]

*Comments are slightly different, only difference in code is an unnecessary `PUSH/POP DX` which was removed, the results are the same*

The debugger also shows `STOSB` incrementing `DI` at each call, as expected. I tried using `LEA DI, [SBUFF + 0]`, no difference. Not using `CLD` also made no difference. Kinda lost here.

Comment: `STOSB` uses the `ES` segment, which your code doesn't set up, and on your screenshot it seems to be different from `DS`. You should either set up `ES` or use a `DS:` segment override.

Comment: @Jester You are right, I didn't see that. However, fixing it ([ES now == DS](http://i.imgur.com/ayQ07Qt.png)) did not solve the issue, the characters still don't seem to be added to the string (the result is the same as the one posted).

Comment: Well, you have the debugger, check the value of `AL` and where `STOSB` writes it. Compare to known address of `SBUFFL` and use the data pane to examine memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect `DS` and `ES` aren't correctly initialised at all. Following test case works here fine (I didn't change your functions):

```
.MODEL small
.STACK 1000h

.DATA
    SBUFFL DB 40 DUP ('x'),'$'
    FHANDLE DW ?
    CBUFF DB ?
    sample_txt db 'sample.txt',0
    errtxt db 'Error.', 13, 10, '$'

.CODE
main PROC
    mov ax, @data       ; Initialise DS & ES
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax

    mov ax, 3d00h       ; fopen
    lea dx, sample_txt
    int 21h
    jc errexit
    mov [FHANDLE], ax

    Loop:               ; print fgets until "no string"
    call FGETS
    cmp byte ptr [SBUFFL], '$'
    je Endloop
    lea dx, SBUFFL
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h
    call crlf
    jmp Loop
    Endloop:

    mov ah, 3Eh         ; fclose
    mov bx, [FHANDLE]
    int 21h

    mov ax, 4C00h
    int 21h

    errexit:
    lea dx, errtxt
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h
    mov ax, 4C01h
    int 21h
main ENDP

crlf PROC               ; print line feed
    push ds
    push '$$'
    push 0A0Dh
    mov ax, ss
    mov ds, ax
    mov dx, sp
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h
    add sp, 4
    pop ds
    ret
crlf ENDP

FGETC PROC NEAR
    PUSH BX             ; pushs
    PUSH DX
    MOV AH, 03Fh        ; Read from file
    MOV BX, FHANDLE     ; Found at fhandle
    MOV CX, 1           ; Read 1 byte
    LEA DX, CBUFF       ; To cbuff
    INT 21H             ; Do it
    POP DX              ; pops
    POP BX
    RET                 ; return
FGETC ENDP

FGETS PROC NEAR
    PUSH AX             ; (used by fgetc)
    PUSH CX             ; (used by fgetc)
    XOR BX, BX          ; clears our byte counter
    CLD                 ; positive BF (used by STOSB)
    LEA DI, SBUFFL      ; pointer to the string buffer (used by STOSB)

    FGETS_LOOP:         ; read loop
    CALL FGETC          ; read a new char from the file to CBUFF
    CMP AX, CX          ; partial read (EOF)?
    JNE FGETS_RET       ; return

    CMP CBUFF, 13       ; carriage return?
    JE FGETS_RET_I      ; return, increment byte count and handle to account for \r\n
    CMP CBUFF, 10       ; line feed?
    JE FGETS_RET_U      ; return, increment byte count and handle to account for \n
    MOV AL, CBUFF       ; char to be written to buff
    STOSB               ; store string byte (increments DI)
    INC BX              ; increment the byte counter
    JMP FGETS_LOOP      ; loop

    FGETS_RET_U:        ; account for \n
    INC BX              ; increment byte counter
    JMP FGETS_RET       ; return

    FGETS_RET_I:        ; account for \r and \n
    ADD BX, 2           ; increment byte count by 2
    CALL FGETC          ; increment fhandle (to skip \n)

    FGETS_RET:          ; return...
    MOV AL, '$'         ; add 'end of string' char to the buffer
    STOSB               ; ...
    POP CX              ; pops
    POP AX              ; ...
    RET                 ; actually return
FGETS ENDP

END main
```

Comment: They are correctly initialized. Nevertheless I ran your code, it worked. I ran my again, it didn't. I made sure they were essentially the same, recompiled everything, and ta-da, both worked! I ran diff on today's binary and on the binary I had on my backup from two days ago and it is the exact same file that wasn't working two days ago. I haven't got the slightest idea what happened. Some issue with dosbox I guess. Thanks anyway!